# How can i use Fingerprint Manager to get (getFingerId) on android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

i used the code below on android 9 and it's work fine.

```
private void getFingerprintInfo(Context context)
    {
        try {
            FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
            Method method = FingerprintManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getEnrolledFingerprints");
            Object obj = method.invoke(fingerprintManager);

            if (obj != null) {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.hardware.fingerprint.Fingerprint");
                Method getFingerId = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getFingerId");

                for (int i = 0; i < ((List) obj).size(); i++)
                {
                    Object item = ((List) obj).get(i);
                    if(item != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("fingerId: " + getFingerId.invoke(item));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but the same code is not working on android 10.
is there any way to getFingerId in android 10 or any other suggest ?